# Limit amount of latest posts WordPress Theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a WordPress theme for my website and I am re-writing most of the appearance for it. I am looking to create a homepage like thenextweb.com that shows 3 sticky posts on the top of the homepage. My website (www.iamlittle.co.uk/beta) shows all the posts in all of the boxes which I don't want it to do.

Comment: Typically WP has a backend setting: Settings -> Reading

Comment: What code have you used to generate the non-working theme you have? If we can see what you're starting from we'll be able to help you more directly.

Comment: @MariM Although when I do that it will no longer let me use any other way  to get the latest posts. For other ones they will only show once. I just audited my code. [see example](www.iamlittle.co.uk/beta).

Comment: Hey @Guildencrantz, Hey, I'm using this code. <section class="cover-feature cover-feature-smallone featured-post"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="cover-feature-text-item"> <h2><?php the_title();?></h2> <p>By: <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>. Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>.</p> </div></a> </section> . I start the loop at the start of the content element and finish it at the bottom.

Comment: @DuncanMcClean you should edit your question to include the code [with formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) for this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 3,        
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',       
    'post_type'        => 'post',       
    'post_status'      => 'publish'     
);

$my_latest_posts = get_posts( $args );
?>


<?php foreach ( $my_latest_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <section class="cover-feature cover-feature-smallone featured-post">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="cover-feature-text-item">
                <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
                <p>By: <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>. Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>.</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </section>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```